# 'for' loop vs Qt's 'foreach' in C++

Tags: c++, performance, qt, foreach, for-loop

Which is better (or faster), a C++ `for` loop or the `foreach` operator provided by Qt? For example, the following condition

```
QList<QString> listofstrings;
```

Which is better?

```
foreach(QString str, listofstrings)
{
    //code
}
```

or

```
int count = listofstrings.count();
QString str = QString();
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    str = listofstrings.at(i);
    //Code
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note that if you don't plan on modifying the foreach loop variable, you should use a const QString& instead - that has implications on speed as well.

Comment: Here is an explanation of why you want to be careful to include the const: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/01/23/iterating-efficiently/

Comment: The important addition to this question is that you should never ever use Qt `foreach` for non Qt containers, most likely deep copy will be performed and this is the thing you do not want even without profiling it beforehand.

Comment: Since Qt 5.7 the `foreach` macro is deprecated, see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

It really doesn't matter in most cases.

The large number of questions on StackOverflow regarding whether this method or that method is faster, belie the fact that, in the vast majority of cases, code spends most of its time sitting around waiting for users to do something.

If you *are* really concerned, profile it for yourself and act on what you find.

But I think you'll most likely find that only in the most intense data-processing-heavy work does this question matter. The difference may well be only a couple of seconds and even then, only when processing huge numbers of elements.

Get your code working *first*. Then get it working *fast* (and only if you find an actual performance issue).

Time spent optimising before you've finished the functionality and can properly profile, is mostly wasted time.

Comment: The number passed the joke stage long ago. We should write an answer bot that looks for "which is faster" and auto-replies: profile it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771092/is-method-a-faster-than-method-b : let's see if it survives :-)

Comment: Not that it really applies so much to the simple example, but what I like to say is, "Incorrect code is as unoptimized as you can get".

Comment: Ooh, that's a good one, @MB, I'll add that to my list of mantras.

Comment: @Michael that went onto my list as well.

Comment: Most code in a program is only executed a limited number of times, and humans are bad at predicting which code (and humans who think they're good at it are also bad at it).  Micro-optimizing code that isn't executed much is completely pointless.  I'd never micro-optimize without knowing there as a performance issue, or without profiling the code.

Comment: @paxdiablo: “mostly wasted”? Damn close to all. (Very occasionally you know early on that a particular code path is going to be hot and can take special care with it, but it's ever so rare.)

Comment: @JaredPar: a bot seems a bit over the top, but a suggestion when creating the question would be indeed nice. We have the "seems subjective - probably will be closed" one, adding a few more should not be a problem.

Comment: There are cases where code size matters (space-constrained embedded devices, inner loops which must not be bigger than a cache line, etc) and in those cases foreach is a poor choice. A colleague just demonstrated that changing a foreach to a C-style for with an integer counter variable reduced the function in question by 250 bytes (take a look at the expansion of Qt's foreach to see why).

Comment: While this answer would be sufficient as a side comment, it does not answer the question. Scrolling down to the other answers you will actually find an answer and not a thousand times repeated discussion about when people should care about performance.

Comment: @inf.ig.sh, it appeared to answer it well enough for the OP :-) I treat this sort of question similar to things like "how do I use bubblesort to sort a billion items?" or "how do I write an operating system in OOCOBOL?" Sometimes the answer really is "don't do that".

Comment: @paxdiablo I strongly disagree. The answer you have given is "If you're really concerned, profile it for yourself.". Just because you got lucky and the OP did not get the code working first and was doing premature optimization does not mean that its a good answer. You answer would have been really great if you would have actually answered the question like several people below have and THEN added your comment. Just to say test it for yourself if you really need to is not an answer.

Comment: @inf.ig.sh, you seem to have misunderstood the crux of the answer. The suggestion for the OP to profile it themselves was if they were really interested. However, the answer was that they *shouldn't* do this because the difference was almost certainly going to turn out to be irrelevant in the scheme of things (as evidenced by the excellent links provided by other answers). *That* was my answer. If you think it's unhelpful with it, that's what SO votes are for, I suggest you use them rather than trying to convince me. If enough people think as you do, it will have an effect.

Comment: @paxdiablo I did use the votes. SO suggest to add an explanatory comment in case of a downvote. That's exactly what i did.

Comment: I work at a market. A big one. A big one that sells millions of products in one month. And when I need to generate a report of that to the government, it makes a looooot of difference. Using QT's foreach, the report took 4 hours. Simply trading it for normal fors changed the speed to 15 min. So depending on your application, the difference is absurd.

Comment: I believe that in rare cases a common answer can be given to the "which is faster" question for comparing the performance of functions or code snippets. In many cases the compiler(MSVC, gcc ), the platform(windows, mac, linux), the framework with libraries (boost, qt, opencv, libmkl ...etc) as well as the versions of those affect the comparisons so that an advised alternative may not fit for every one.  It is nice to work in your own environment and make your own comparisons either with the profiler or simply measuring the elapsed time on multiple iterations(benchmarking).

Answer (score 25):

First off, I'd just like to say I agree with Pax, and that the speed probably doesn't enter into it. foreach wins hands down based on readability, and that's enough in 98% of cases.

But of course the Qt guys have looked into it and actually done some profiling: 
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/01/23/iterating-efficiently/

The main lesson to take away from that is: use const references in read only loops as it avoids the creation of temporary instances. It also make the purpose of the loop more explicit, regardless of the looping method you use.

Answer (score 19):

**It really doesn't matter**. Odds are if your program is slow, this isn't the problem. However, it should be noted that you aren't make a completely equal comparison. Qt's `foreach` is more similar to this (this example will use `QList<QString>`):

```
for(QList<QString>::iterator it = Con.begin(); it != Con.end(); ++it) {
    QString &str = *it;
    // your code here
}
```

The macro is able to do this by using some compiler extensions (like GCC's `__typeof__`) to get the type of the container passed. Also imagine that boost's `BOOST_FOREACH` is very similar in concept.

The reason why your example isn't fair is that your non-Qt version is adding extra work.

You are indexing instead of really iterating. If you are using a type with non-contiguous allocation (I suspect this might be the case with `QList<>`), then indexing will be more expensive since the code has to calculate "where" the n-th item is.

That being said. It **still** doesn't matter. The timing difference between those two pieces of code will be negligible if existent at all. Don't waste your time worrying about it. Write whichever you find more clear and understandable.

**EDIT:** As a bonus, currently I strongly favor the C++11 version of container iteration, it is clean, concise and simple:

```
for(QString &s : Con) {
    // you code here
}
```

Comment: Your statement concerning `at()` vs `operator[]` performance is not correct for Qt. Both do or do not perform bounds checking depending on compilation options. Exceptions are not used in Qt. In contrast, the [documentation says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) "`at()` can be faster than `operator[]()`, because it never causes a deep copy to occur."

Answer (score 18):

Since **Qt 5.7** the `foreach` macro is deprecated, Qt encourages you to use the C++11 `for` instead.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#foreach

(more details about the difference here : https://www.kdab.com/goodbye-q_foreach/)

Comment: Please also add this as a comment to the question, more people need to see this!

Answer (score 13):

I don't want to answer the question which is faster, but I do want to say which is better.

The biggest problem with Qt's foreach is the fact that it takes a copy of your container before iterating over it. You could say 'this doesn't matter because Qt classes are refcounted' but because a copy is used you don't actually change your original container at all.

In summary, Qt's foreach can only be used for read-only loops and thus should be avoided. Qt will happily let you write a foreach loop which you think will update/modify your container but in the end all changes are thrown away.

Comment: I agree. I ran into a `foreach` while profiling: It turned out I had changed a `QList` to a `QVarLengthArray` (again after profiling) and found the `foreach` copying my `QVarLengthArray`. Oops. I went for a regular `for` loop and that stack trace no longer showed up in the profiler.

Answer (score 4):

First, I completely agree with the answer that "it doesn't matter". Pick the cleanest solution, and optimize if it becomes a problem.

But another way to look at it is that often, the fastest solution is the one that describes your intent most accurately. In this case, QT's foreach says that you'd like to apply some action for each element in the container.

A plain for loop say that you'd like a counter `i`. You want to repeatedly add one to this value i, and as long as it is less than the number of elements in the container, you would like to perform some action.

In other words, the plain for loop overspecifies the problem. It adds a lot of requirements that aren't actually part of what you're trying to do. You don't *care* about the loop counter. But as soon as you write a for loop, it has to be there.

On the other hand, the QT people have made no additional promises that may affect performance. They simply guarantee to iterate through the container and apply an action to each.

In other words, often the cleanest and most elegant solution is also the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

The foreach from Qt has a clearer syntax for the for loop IMHO, so it's better in that sense. Performance wise I doubt there's anything in it.

You could consider using the [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach.html) instead, as it is a well thought out fancy for loop, and it's portable (and presumably will make it's way into C++ some day and is future proof too).

Answer (score 3):

A benchmark, and its results, on this can be found at http://richelbilderbeek.nl/CppExerciseAddOneAnswer.htm

IMHO (and many others here) it (that is speed) does not matter.

But feel free to draw your own conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

For small collections, it should matter and foreach tends to be clearer.

However, for larger collections, for will begin to beat foreach at some point.  (assuming that the 'at()' operator is efficient.

If this is really important (and I'm assuming it is since you are asking) then the best thing to do is measure it.  A profiler should do the trick, or you could build a test version with some instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect foreach to work nominally faster in some cases, and the about same in others, except in cases where the items are an actual array in which case the performace difference is negligible.

If it is implemented on top of an enumerator, it *may* be more efficient than a straight indexing, depending on implementation. It's unlikely to be less efficient. For example, if someone exposed a balanced tree as both indexable and enumerable, then foreach will be decently faster. This is because each index will have to independently find the referenced item, while an enumerator has the context of the current node to more efficiently navigate to the next ont.

If you have an actual array, then it depends on the implementation of the language and class whether foreach will be faster for the same as for.

If indexing is a literal memory offset(such as C++), then for should be marginally faster since you're avoiding a function call. If indexing is an indirection just like a call, then it should be the same.

All that being said... I find it hard to find a case for generalization here. This is the last sort of optimization you should be looking for, even if there is a performance problem in your application. If you have a performance problem that can be solved by changing how you iterate, you don't really have a performance problem. You have a BUG, because someone wrote either a really crappy iterator, or a really crappy indexer.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the STL's [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) function.  I don't know whether it will be faster than the two options you present, but it is more standardized than the Qt foreach and avoids some of the problems that you may run into with a regular for loop (namely out of bounds indexing and difficulties with translating the loop to a different data structure).

Comment: IMO, STL is not more "standard" than Qt. STL-style code is often extremely ugly. If you have to integrate with non-Qt C++ apps/libs, then it may be worthwhile. If you're just building a Qt app, using STL functions doesn't help you at all, instead, you'll be typecasting all the time.