# Is the second term in Qt's foreach evaluated only once?

Tags: c++, qt

If I have this code:

```
foreach (QListWidgetItem *ii, selectedItems()) {
    urls.push_back(ii->data(Qt::ToolTip).toString());
}
```

Would `selectedItems()` be called only once?

Comment: Regarding the performance part, just read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771008/for-loop-vs-foreach-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. It will create a copy of the returned container, and use that. (See [Qt foreach keyword](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword) documentation)

*Related:*

- Since Qt foreach always copies the container, it's best used with either QT-containers (which are copy-on-write) or small STL containers.
- [Boost's foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/foreach.html) handles this better, and avoids copies unless necessary.

Comment: On the other hand, copying allows modifying the original container in the loop without breaking anything. Or is it safe with Boost too? Never actually used it.

Comment: @Sergey: True, however I'd make an explicit copy in that case, since, in my experience, the far more common case is that I either don't want to modify anything (i.e. just iterate), or modify the original container.

Comment: true, but in Qt it sometimes happens that the container is modified implicitly inside the loop. For example, there may be some method call in the loop that emis a signal, and then some slot connected to that signal modifies the container. This isn't as bad as with multi-threading as everything still happens inside one thread, but the sequence of method calls can be not very obvious.

Comment: @Sergey: Yeah. If that happens, default copy is nice to have. :)