# PHP How do you create an increasing number array?

Tags: php, arrays, counting

as the title says i am trying to create an increasing numbers array for example:

I have a number 30 and i want to create an array out of it like

```
$numbers = array(6,12,18,24,30);
// then extract data from mysql
foreach( $numbers as $LIMITNUMBER ){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=id ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 0,".$LIMITNUMBER;
}
```

The 30 number above could be any number 100 or 200 but it always divides by 6 so the array first  value has to be 6 and then +6 addition to the previous value.

Comment: http://php.net/range But even if you didn't know about that function - why didn't you try `for` and assemble an array manually?

Comment: Fed thank you, 
@zerkms, honestly you can not assume every one is php freak, because the number is not manual its generated from another query.

Comment: it has nothing to do with being a "freak" or however you call it - the `for` is the language structure one should learn at the very first day after you meet the language. So even if you didn't know about `range` (which is fine) - you could do what you need using plain old `for` (which is just pity)

Comment: :) What if some one is paying some one full time to do something and then he has to do it himself? i will keep learning thank you **for** your help @zerkms

Comment: "and then they have to do it himself" --- they just need to learn the very basics before they even try to implement something. That's how you're supposed to learn something - from the basics to the complex things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a function implementing PHP 'range'.

Here's an example based on your question:

```
function incrementToMax($max) {
    foreach (range(6, $max, 6) as $currentMax) {
       $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=id ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 0,".$currentMax;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
incrementToMax(60);
```

Comment: "The easiest way to do this would be to use a function implementing PHP 'range'." --- how about `for($i = 6; $i <= $max; $i+=6)`?

Comment: @zerkms Well both do exactly the same thing? Since PHP added a function specifically for this situation, it seemed more appropriate.

Comment: "added a function specifically for this sort of thing" --- actually, **NO**. OP doesn't need an array, OP needs to iterate over number with step=6. That's what `for` was developed for. The fact that you could use `range()` for that doesn't mean it was designed specifically for it.

Comment: @zerkms This seems like a very opinionated, hence pointless discussion? Both options have minimal performance differences when working with numbers this small, so again; pointless to debate this.

Comment: there wouldn't be debates at all if you didn't state it as an "easiest way". The most natural way - is to use `for`. Just because `for` is designed to iterate.

Comment: @zerkms I'm going to refer to this simply because this is going nowhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771008/for-loop-vs-qts-foreach-in-c This will be my last comment on this question.

Comment: the question you've given a reference to is about **performance** of foreach vs for in **C++**. Not sure how it's relevant about `range()` (which isn't there at all) in php. But I'm used to see a lot of pointless arguments here on SO, it's just another one :-D